# setup ngnix and passenger to run VueJS

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vuejs2, passenger

I am trying to run A vuejs application on a server with Nginx + Passenger.

My host config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hostname.dev;

    root /home/ubuntu/vueapp/current;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file build/webpack.prod.conf.js;
}
```

I am deploying the application using capistrano + capistrano-npm

After capistrano deploys the app, it runs this:

> 00:13 deploy:set_current_revision
>         01 echo "56afbb253bd70b118aeee25ec20083c7ccafc96b" >> REVISION
>       ✔ 01 ubuntu@192.168.33.14 0.045s 00:13 npm:install
>         01 npm install --production --silent --no-progress
>         01 added 2 packages in 3.963s
>       ✔ 01 ubuntu@192.168.33.14 4.911s

The problem is that when I visit my host `hostname.dev` I see a blank page. Inspecting the source, I see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>vuedemo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Evidently Vue is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any javascript files included in that HTML.  Did you add the script?

Comment: @Jeff it is not supposed to be included automatically ?

Comment: I don't know how passenger works, sorry. But I do know theres no javascript included in that page code

Comment: @Jeff if you want to deploy you Vue app, production mode, what do you do? which softwares do you need to run your app ?

Comment: @Vinicius I think the mistake is that you're passing your webpack file thinking it will run the build, but instead you should be passing the already built file to it. Can you try that?

Comment: @Vinicius have you read this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#With-Build-Tools It looks like in production mode there is no Javascript runtime for vue.js, it's simply static html, css, and js. So you just need to tell webpack to build your files and then put them all in the document root. In fact unless there is a Javascript (or ruby or python) runtime involved, you don't need passenger at all.